# Groovy: How to replace leftShift operator in these cases?

Tags: groovy, deprecated

I have the next call to a plugin in my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.company.gradleplugins.plugin'
```

When I compile, Jenkins is warning me about Gradle 5.0 and its deprecations:

> The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is
>   scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action)
>   instead.
>
> at build_c4218hywg.run(/Users/user/Documents/project/projectfolder/app/build.gradle:12)

The standard replace is clear (using `doLast` instead `<<`), but I've found some operations which I don't know how to update (the whole project is not only mine).

So, in the plugin, I have some of these:

```
configJSON = mainProperties.getConfig() << buildProperties.getConfig()

imageNames << image.getFileName()

for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
    list << m[i][1]
}
```

And so on. Which is the current way to do this?

Comment: They're fine. The warning is specific to tasks

Comment: I thought so but I've not found any task in the project. I guess I should check it.

Comment: What's on build.gradle line 12?

Comment: A call to a plugin: ```apply plugin: 'com.company.gradleplugins.pluginname'```

Comment: Ahhh, so that plugin probably uses left shift with tasks and needs updating to use doLast. Is it a plugin you manage and have the source for?

Comment: Yes, the code is actually from that plugin. Maybe I should make it clear in the original post.

Comment: So as long as you've fixed the `task xxx << ...` in the plugin, the warning should go away

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, finally I've found the line in the plugin project.

There was the next code block:

```
if(it.hasProperty("android")) { 
    project.task('mainTask') << {
        ...
    }
}
```

So the solution is:

```
if(it.hasProperty("android")) {
    project.task('mainTask') {
        doLast {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

My fault.

Answer (score 1):

`Task.leftShift(Closure)` - this is leftShift() for Task class from Gradle lib.

`imageNames << image.getFileName()` - this is leftShift() for Collection class and it is a part of Groovy language.

If you'll check **org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods** you'll see that:

`imageNames << image.getFileName()`

is same

`imageNames.add(image.getFileName())`